# How do galvanic cells work?

Tags: electrochemistry

I was wondering how a galvanic cell works

If you look at the picture below, if I have magnesium metal in sulfuric acid, will the metal react with the acid to be then turned into magnesium ions and in the process give away 2 electrons and that is how electrons are given in any cell: the electrode interacts with the electrolyte in the anode and then gives up electrons? And if this is the case, then why wouldn't the zinc replace copper in copper sulfate at the cathode and also give 2 electrons away?

What am I doing that is wrong?

[image: galvanic cell]

Comment: This galvanic cell is bad in that _each_ half-cell would readily react on its own (zinc would replace copper, magnesium would replace hydrogen). That being said, it still might be able to produce some current.

Comment: ok then how should one choose an electrolyte

Comment: Choose it so that it would not react with the corresponding electrode. In this case, $\ce{MgSO4}$ and $\ce{ZnSO4}$ would do.

Comment: so if the electrodes don't react with the electrolyte, then how do they give electrons?

Comment: Like always: ions to the solution, electrons to the wire.

Comment: so if would change the electrolyte, what would your different electrolytes be? And again, how are the electrons given if the electrode doesn't interact with the electrolyte

Comment: Basically, I am trying to ask is if you take a zinc copper battery, zinc replaces copper sulfate in solution and thus gives away 2 electrons. But this is when zinc is physically in copper sulfate solution. However, when they make a zinc-copper cell, they put zinc in zinc sulfate solution (and copper in copper sulfate solution), then how does the zinc give up its 2 electrons?

Comment: When zinc is physically in copper sulfate solution, this is not a galvanic cell, or probably a bad galvanic cell like your initial example. Like I said, the electrolyte should not be able to react with the electrode _on its own_ (without the wire).

Comment: Ya so then how does the electrode give up its electron?

Comment: Like always: ions to the solution, electrons to the wire.

Comment: could you please go into detail and explain what that means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanic_cell

Comment: my question is what is responsible for the electrons? The metal electrode just can't magically donate its electrons?

Comment: Yes it can, though not magically.

Comment: could you explain that? because from what i have read, when you place an electrode in a solution, the metal will interact with the solution

Comment: okay so let's say I put sodium bicarbonate with magnesium, would the cell work then?

Comment: Yes, it would. But then again, your initial design would work too, just not very efficiently, because some material would be lost to the side reactions. You got rid of the side reaction with Mg, but you still have the one with Zn.

Comment: alright so then if I put copper and copper sulfate instead of zinc, would that work?

Comment: Yes, it would surely be better this way.

Comment: and electrons will be transferred from one electrode to other?

Comment: Yes, they will (if you connect them with a wire, that is).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ivan it's a really bad galvanic cell and both metals would displace the components of the respective containers .But still one of them is more electropositive than other hence there would be some net flow of electrons .You can also compare cells by comparison of electrode potential of respective half cells which in your case have same sign and hence EMF net would be low .

Comment: my question is what is responsible for the electrons? The metal electrode just can't magically donate its electrons?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that it would not work. In a galvanic cell they should create an electron potential, but in your cell, half cell would react within itself, so no electron potential will be created. The one with $\ce{Mg}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{Mg}$ will displace $\ce{H2}$ creating $\ce{MgSO4}$. In a cell it is necessary to have a similar salt in container to the plate we have taken, here it is of $\ce{Mg}$ so that they would not react itself rather react with the one in other half cell. I hope that this will be enough. I am ready to help you further.